# How to create List<T> instance in C# file

Tags: c#, list, generics, reflection

I have theese classes:

```
public class BaseGrid
{
    public int current { get; set; }
    public int rowCount { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
    public List<T> rows { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Back in my controller, I´d like to do something like:

```
        List<Product> listOfProducts = new List<Product>();

        BaseGrid baseGrid = new BaseGrid();
        baseGrid.rowCount = 10;
        baseGrid.total = 20;
        baseGrid.current = 1;
        baseGrid.rows = listOfProducts;
```

How can I do to "rows" property became a **generic** list and in instance in **runtime** the baseGrid.rows to whatever list type I want?

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: `BaseGrid` needs to be generic.

Comment: @Amy: Generics are a compile-time concept, even when you are specifying the concrete type.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm aware.  I think you and I interpreted the question very differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 public class BaseGrid<T> where T : class
{
    public int current { get; set; }
    public int rowCount { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
    public List<T> rows { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to explicitly declare a generic constructor if you don't have any other constructors defined.

Comment: @nulltron: You still need to initialize the list.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I didn't realize you were talking about the list lol

Comment: Well, why else would you bother making the thing generic? :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Because generics are *awesome*.

Comment: Typically I'll populate on the fly with a result set from a query or something so I rarely initialize the list to empty. I utilize it being not initialized to identify specific issues.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is runtime polymorphism.

```
public abstract class Animal
{
  public abstract void makeSound()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("[nothing happens]");
  }
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
  public override void makeSound()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Meow");
  }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
  public override void makeSound()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Woof");
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    var animals = new List<Animal>();
    animals.Add(new Dog());
    animals.Add(new Cat());
    Console.Add(animals[0].MakeSound());  // Woof
    Console.Add(animals[1].MakeSound());  // Meow
}
```